# Automate Test Orders

Tags: language-agnostic

I need a way to automate test orders on our test and production web sites. I was thinking about using something like iMacro, but I thought there must be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: serverside tests or javascript tests?
unit tests or integration tests?

Answer (score 3):

Another good FF add-in is [Selenium IDE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2079) which seems a bit more feature rich than the add-in for iMacros. There are extended editions ([Selenium](http://selenium.openqa.org/),[iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/)) that you can pay for that include command line scripting, recording page timings etc.

I'm just evaluating both to see which handles Flash better and Selenium wants code added to the Action Script which with our old flash games isn't as simple as using iMacros co-ordinate based clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what kind of "order" you're talking about, it's really impossible to say.

I suspect that you don't *really* want to be creating test orders on a production system though.